# Git: rebase merge commit "--preserve-merges"

Tags: git, git-rebase

I found that git offers the option "--preserve-merges" for rebasing merge commits.

My Problem is now: When I have to do a difficult merge with lots of merge conflicts and then  do "git rebase --preserve-merges", what happens is the git actually wants me to do the whole merge again. It forgets my conflict resolutions from before and presents the same conflicts again.

So my question is the following: Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? Is there any work-around that Git remembers the already resolved conflicts?

Here a more detailed description on what I want to do:

Actually, my goal is to merge branch master2 to branch master1. When I am finally done with merge commit M, other developers have committed B and C to the master1. So I would like to rebase now.

```
- A - B - C <- master1
   \
    M <- topic
   /
- X <- master2
```

After rebase:

```
- A - B - C <- master1
           \
            M' <- topic
           /
        - X <- master2
```

Thanks and Best regards.

Comment: Turn on `git rerere` (see `git config` documentation, look for all occurrences of `rerere`, and `git rerere` documentation).